# c# Convert datagridview data from EURO to UK

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have some data in a datagridview

Here is an example of the data: 
      91    154 70  309 83  6451
      91    154 70  309 83  6451
      92    160 75  309 87  5687
      94    173 80  309 87  5687
      96    187 87  309 95  4662

I have each value storing and displaying in the datagridview correctly but would like to update the values For example i have 154 storing as 15.4 which is KPH but would like to display the value in MPH which would be 9.56912 when the UK radio button is selected

I have stored the data in arrays [Darray] 
i just need to update the values stored in Darray[2] and Darray [4]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your radio button event, you can just create new arrays containing the UK measurements based on your original data and then set those new arrays as the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`.